# How to call karate feature file into karate-config.js file

Tags: javascript, access-token, karate

I'm trying to call Access token API into karate-config.js file, and write a code to generate new token when token gets expired and use the token globally in all the feature files. Is there a way to call karate feature file into karate-config.js file?